# ondrop event not firing

Tags: javascript, html

Context: Working on a webpage to be able to dragdrop a csv file onto it and load data infile to MySQL server. Running on Widnows 7 SP1, serving on Apache 2.4, testing on localhost using Chrome.

Problem: Trying to create the upload page but I can't get the `ondrop` event to fire. I have escaped the default behavior to my understanding but still get no response from the live webpage. I also did the same with the `ondragenter` event (not shown) with no change. Treatment is that the file downloads through the browser to default downloads folder which is also what happens when dropping file to the rest of the page (ergo default treatment?). I believe the drag and drop API is native to most browsers and doesn't require any included library. Is this wrong and I'm missing some definitions?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            #drop_zone {
                background-color: #EEE;
                border: #999 5px dashed;
                width: 290px;
                height: 200px;
                padding: 8px;
                font-size: 18px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
        function drag_enter(event) {
            document.getElementById("drop_zone").style.border = "5px dotted red";
        function drag_drop(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert(event.dataTransfer.files[0]);
            alert(event.dataTransfer.files[0].name);
            alert(event.dataTransfer.files[0].size+" bytes");

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>File Upload Drop Zone</h1>
    <div id="drop_zone" ondragenter="drag_enter(event)" ondrop="drag_drop(event)" ondragover="return false"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Additional question: can someone explain on the HTML event caller what the parameter (called `event`) passed to the function represents? Is it that particular event ID? Can you refer the caller of the event by this? Not sure I understand the relationship between the caller and the function in regards to this parameter. Online documentation usually glazes over explaining its use.

Thank you anyone taking the time to review my question. Warm regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing some closing `}` at the end of each of your functions, this:

```
 function drag_enter(event) {
            document.getElementById("drop_zone").style.border = "5px dotted red";
        function drag_drop(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert(event.dataTransfer.files[0]);
            alert(event.dataTransfer.files[0].name);
            alert(event.dataTransfer.files[0].size+" bytes");
```

should be:

```
function drag_enter(event) {
  document.getElementById("drop_zone").style.border = "5px dotted red";
}
function drag_drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert(event.dataTransfer.files[0]);
  alert(event.dataTransfer.files[0].name);
  alert(event.dataTransfer.files[0].size + " bytes");
}
```

Here is a [working example](http://codepen.io/pabs123/pen/jVobGm)

Comment: Boooom, awesome! I was hurting my head thinking of it being something big. Little details make all the difference. I am marking this as correct answer. If someone has the impetus to answer my second question I will also shower them with praise and fake internet points.